# What happend if i use static keyword fo check the size

Tags: c, programming-languages

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct st
{
    int x;
    static int y;
};
int main()   
{
    printf("%d", sizeof(struct st));
    return 0;
}
```

What happens if I use static in c language and what happens if I have to use %ld for getting a size of structure

Comment: Compilation error will happen. You can't have static member in a structure *definition*.

Comment: Members of a `struct` can't be `static`.

Answer (score 0):

> What happend if i use static in c language

From the C Standard (6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers)

```
1 storage-class-specifier:
    typedef
    extern
    static
    _Thread_local
    auto
    register
```

and (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

```
struct-declaration:
    specifier-qualifier-list struct-declarator-listopt ;
    static_assert-declaration

specifier-qualifier-list:
    type-specifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
    type-qualifier specifier-qualifier-listopt
```

That is a member declaration may not have the storage-class specifier.

> what happend i i have to use %ld for getting a size of structure

There can be undefined behavior because the value returned by the operator `sizeof` has the type `size_t`. You have to use the conversion specifier `%zu` instead of `%d`.

Comment: Should use `%zu` for portable version to print `size_t` type. `printf("%zu" sizeof(...));`. - Just adding to answer.